# How to update (some files) a Symfony2 project to remote

Tags: symfony, web-deployment

I've been developing with Symfony1.4 'till now and had no problem to deploy a project or update it into a remote hosting. I just used sfFtpPlugin and everything was perfect: http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfFtpPlugin

But now I'm starting with Symfony2 (2.2.0) and the first of all I had this question: how to update it when I make changes?

For the first time deploy I know there are some options: upload full project by FTP or use Maestro (e.g. offered in the ServerGrove.com hostings) With those tools I can upload everything, but in the case where I need to update... ¿50? files, I cannot manually do by FTP, of course.

Thanks everyone for helping!

P.S: Aditional info: I have some SVN knowledge and started learning GIT a few days ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation on this is fantastic. The Cookbook provides workflows for both Git and SVN.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/workflow/index.html

If you have no shell available, you can use composer on your local machine to update your project and then FTP the entire project over.

This covers how to store settings for different environments:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/environments.html

Personally I use a private [Satis](https://github.com/composer/satis) repo for deploying all my code.

That way I never have to use FTP, just composer create-project/install/update.

Comment: Thanks for answering, james_t! Both solutions you gave me look interesting, hummmm... I'll check patiently when I have more free time, but thank you very much ^_^